# Httpd Apache multiple virtual host - enable https on specific domain

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, https, virtualhost

I have 3 sites (site1, site 2, site3) run on same IP server. Now, I want to add ssl and redirect http to https for site1 only. Site2 and site 3 still run in http. This is my httpd configs:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    Redirect / https://site1.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
    ServerName site1.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
    ServerName site2.com 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
    ServerName site3.com
</VirtualHost>
```

> OS : CentOS 6.9 - Apache : 2.2.15

When I restart the apache, I get FAILED result without message. How can I setup the server as my expectation ? 
Thanks !